# Opening a .osx file in default program

Tags: macos, file-extension

I'm trying to run Fluenz on my computer and it's a .osx file. When I try to open it, it opens in Textmate. Kind of odd. Does anyone know how to restore its original default program? I think that I might have changed all .osx files to open in Textmate some time in the past for a programming project, but I don't know what the original was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no *real* default program, as the file type is apparently not known by OS X (at least on my system). It depends on the applications you installed on your system.

---

You can always right-click and select *Open With…* to see which applications claim support the file type.
If the desired program is in the list, you can *Get Info* the file, and then change the program to use for opening all files of this kind.
This setting is in the *Open with* section by selecting it and then pressing *Change All…*.

> [image]

---

To remove the custom association with TextMate, remove the matching entry from `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist` in the `LSHandlers` section and reset the Launch Services database by running the following in Terminal:

> `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r domain local -r domain system -r domain user`

Comment: The last step might be overkill. Edit the `plist` and restart your system to see what happens before resetting Launch Services.